# Passing onselect value from menu component to another component reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I've been trying to achieve a function that I am not sure of, I have a component that renders JSON file and shows products named 'product list', another component named 'person' which is used to show product items, both are working fine, but the third component called menucat includes the scrolling menu from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu, the onselect function of the menu component returns an id number on selection, I want to pass that number inside the mapping function within the productlist.

Product list

```
import React from "react";
import Person from "./Person";MenuCat";
import MenuCat, {a, onSelect, selected}  from "../components/


class ProductList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    items: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("items.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },

        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }


  render() {

    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return (
        <div>
          Error:{" "}
          {error.message  }
          {console.log("check 1:", items)}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return (
        <div>
          <img
            src="loading.gif"
            alt="loading"
            height="100"
          />
        </div>
      );
    } else { 
       return (
        <div>
          <MenuCat />
          <div className="row">
            {items.children[0].children.map(item => (
              <Person
                className="person"
                Key={item.name}
                Title={item.name}
                imgSrc={item.image_url}
              >

                {item.base_price}  
              </Person>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
     }
  }
}
```

and the menuCat component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ScrollMenu from "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu";
import "../menu.css";

// list of items


const list  = [
  { name: "category1" , id : 0},
  { name: "category2" , id : 1},
  { name: "category3" , id : 2},
  { name: "category4" , id : 3},
  { name: "category5" , id : 4},
  { name: "category6" , id : 5},
  { name: "category7" , id : 6},

];


// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return <div className="menu-item">{text}</div>;
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = list =>
  list.map(el => {
    const { name } = el;
    const { id } = el;

    return <MenuItem text={name} key={id} />;
  });

const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return <div className={className}>{text}</div>;
};

const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: "<", className: "arrow-prev" });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: ">", className: "arrow-next" });

export class Menucat extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: "0"
  };

  onSelect = key => {
    console.log(`onSelect: ${key}`);
    this.setState({ selected: key});
  };

  render() {
    const { selected  } = this.state;
     // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(list, selected);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
           onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

 export default Menucat;
```

I want the id generated from onselect function to be added instead of 0 in

```
            {items.children[0].children.map(item => (
```

so that whenever the user clicks on a category item, the id of that category goes to the mapping function which will do the rest. I am aware that the category list is hardcoded, for now, I just want this communication between the components to happen, I want to pass the id from the menucat component to a something like a variable in product list that can go instead of the zero like `{items.children[selected].children.map(item => (`

Comment: Are you using redux in your application? React doesn't have a way to pass properties back up the component tree (this is by design). State management between components or back up the component tree is left to third party libraries in React, of which Redux is the most common. If you are unfamiliar with this, I'd be happy to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to add an 'onSelect' prop to MenuCat to pass through the ScrollMenu's onSelect results, then a state value in ProductList to store the selected key.  something like this:

ProductList

```js
import React from "react";
import Person from "./Person";MenuCat";
import MenuCat, {a, onSelect, selected}  from "../components/


class ProductList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        items: [],
        selected: 0,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("items.json")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                result => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result
                    });
                },

                error => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            );
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onSelect(key) {
        this.setState({selected: key});
    }


    render() {

        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return (
                <div>
                Error:{" "}
            {error.message  }
            {console.log("check 1:", items)}
        </div>
        );
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return (
                <div>
                <img
            src="loading.gif"
            alt="loading"
            height="100"
                />
                </div>
        );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                <MenuCat onSelect={this.onSelect} />
                <div className="row">
                {items.children[this.state.selected].children.map(item => (
                    <Person
            className="person"
            Key={item.name}
            Title={item.name}
            imgSrc={item.image_url}
        >

            {item.base_price}
        </Person>
        ))}
        </div>
            </div>
        );
        }
    }
}
```

and MenuCat like

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ScrollMenu from "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu";
import "../menu.css";

// list of items


const list  = [
    { name: "category1" , id : 0},
    { name: "category2" , id : 1},
    { name: "category3" , id : 2},
    { name: "category4" , id : 3},
    { name: "category5" , id : 4},
    { name: "category6" , id : 5},
    { name: "category7" , id : 6},

];


// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
    return <div className="menu-item">{text}</div>;
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = list =>
    list.map(el => {
        const { name } = el;
        const { id } = el;

        return <MenuItem text={name} key={id} />;
    });

const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
    return <div className={className}>{text}</div>;
};

const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: "<", className: "arrow-prev" });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: ">", className: "arrow-next" });

export class Menucat extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: "0"
    };

    onSelect = key => {
        console.log(`onSelect: ${key}`);
        this.setState({ selected: key});
        this.props.onSelect(key);
    };

    render() {
        const { selected  } = this.state;
        // Create menu from items
        const menu = Menu(list, selected);

        return (
            <div className="App">
            <ScrollMenu
        data={menu}
        arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
        arrowRight={ArrowRight}
        selected={selected}
        onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default Menucat;
```

you pass an 'onSelect' function to menucat, menucat calls it when the item is selected, and back in ProductList, its 'onSelect' function is then run, setting state which can then be used in your item selection.

make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much, it did make alot of sense